# JQuery FancyBox: Passar um parâmetro para uma janela inline

Tags: fancybox

Tenho 5 botões que abrem uma janela usando Fancybox inline modal, e no momento que abrir essa janela preciso pegar um parametro ou alguma forma de mostrar qual foi o botão que disparou o evento:

```
    <a class="btn btn-success fancybox1" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoDinheiro">F2 - DINHEIRO</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary fancybox2" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCheque">F3 - CHEQUE</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger fancybox3" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCartaoCredito">F4 - CARTÃO CRÉDITO</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info fancybox4" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCartaoDebito">F5 - CARTÃO DÉBITO</a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning fancybox5" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCrediario">F6 - CREDIÁRIO LOJA</a>

                <div id="divFormaPgto" style="display: none">
                    <h1 onclick="alert($.fancybox.FormaPgto);">RECEBIDO</h1>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <br />
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
                </div>
```

.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.fancybox1').fancybox({
        'modal': true,
        'FormaPgto': 'dinheiro'
    });

    $('a.fancybox2').fancybox({
        'modal': true
    });

    $('a.fancybox3').fancybox({
        'modal': true
    });

    $('a.fancybox4').fancybox({
        'modal': true
    });

    $('a.fancybox5').fancybox({
        'modal': true
    });
});
    </script>
```

Eu estava tentando passar dessa forma, mas FormaPgto sempre sai undefined, teria outra forma mais adequada?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar um atributo `data-tipopag` em cada link `<a>` que irá abrir o modal e capturar depois:

```
<a data-tipopag="Dinheiro" class="btn btn-success fancybox" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoDinheiro">F2 - DINHEIRO</a>
<a data-tipopag="Cheque" class="btn btn-primary fancybox" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCheque">F3 - CHEQUE</a>
<a data-tipopag="Cartão de Crédito" class="btn btn-danger fancybox" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCartaoCredito">F4 - CARTÃO CRÉDITO</a>
<a data-tipopag="Cartão de Débito" class="btn btn-info fancybox" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCartaoDebito">F5 - CARTÃO DÉBITO</a>
<a data-tipopag="Crediário Loja" class="btn btn-warning fancybox" href="#divFormaPgto" style="font-size: 22px; width: 100%;" id="btnPtgoCrediario">F6 - CREDIÁRIO LOJA</a>
```

E incluir um script que captura a informação e joga pra dentro do modal:

```
$("a.fancybox").on("click",function(){
    $("#divFormaPgto h1").attr("onclick","alert('"+$(this).attr("data-tipopag")+"')");
});
```

Não precisar aplicar o Fancybox para cada link no script, basta chamá-lo 1 vez:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        'modal': true
    });
});
```

Coloque a classe `fancybox` em todos os links `<a>`, e não fancybox1, fancybox2...

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado.